# I want to keep asking for input until valid input provided form scanner

Tags: java, exception

I am learning to handle exception and In `try` block if i get character input in `arr[i]` then I want the catch block to ask for array input again.
But the catch block array input code is throwing error.

```
package Day2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestinArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enter 5 number");
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int arr[]=new int[5];


   try{
       for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
           arr[i]=scanner.nextInt();
       }
   }catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("error");
       for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
           arr[i]=scanner.nextInt();
       }

   }

    findLarge(arr);


}

private static void findLarge(int[] arr) {
    int max=arr[0],min=arr[0];
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if (arr[i]>max){
            max=arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i]<min){
            min=arr[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("max is"+max+"min is"+min);
}
}
```

This is the error i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at Day2.LargestinArray.main(LargestinArray.java:19)
```

Comment: You're trying to re-execute the same code that potentially throws an error inside of your catch block. Don't do that. EDIT: [Here's the documentation for that error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html), as well.

Comment: @Mazzone I want user to re-enter again in catch block how can i achieve that

Comment: Try putting your try/catch block into a while loop that will end after correct input.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will try reading the scanner input and it'll try again and again until it succeeds reading 5 ints in a row. If you don't necessarily want the correct inputs to be consecutive write a comment below and I'll edit this answer.

```
boolean isDone = false;
while (!isDone) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        isDone = true;
    } catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("error");           
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the user enters non-integer input – `scanner.nextInt()` will not consume that input, so after the first occurrrence of something like "a", this code will print "error" forever without looking at any other input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to read input, looping indefinitely until five consecutive integers are found.

Note that instead of using `scanner.nextInt()`, I'm using `scanner.next()`. The reason is that `nextInt()` will leave unconsumed non-integer input still sitting on the scanner – that is, if there's something non-integer waiting such as a string, that string still be there when you call `nextInt()` again. You could make `scanner.nextInt()` work by calling `scanner.next()` inside the catch block but there might be more to consider about whether that creates any other issues.

```
private static int[] getNumbers() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        try {
            int[] numbers = new int[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                String next = scanner.next();
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(next);
            }
            return numbers;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can call the function like this:

```
int[] numbers = getNumbers();
System.out.println("numbers: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
```